# org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.horariolivre.entity.Key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

In my spring application, I am trying persist in database the follow entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuario")
public class Usuario implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7283129128268761582L;

    private int id;
    private String login;
    private String senha;
    private String primeiroNome;
    private String ultimoNome;
    private Tipo tipo;
    private List<Atributo> atributo;
    private ConfigHorarioLivre config;
    private List<Autorizacao> autorizacao;

    public Usuario() {
    }

    public Usuario(String login, String senha) {
        this.setLogin(login);
        this.setSenha(senha);
    }

    public Usuario(String login, String senha, String primeiroNome, String ultimoNome, Tipo tipo, List<Atributo> atributos) {
        this.setLogin(login);
        this.setSenha(senha);
        this.setPrimeiroNome(primeiroNome);
        this.setUltimoNome(ultimoNome);
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.atributo = atributos;
        this.config = new ConfigHorarioLivre();
        this.autorizacao = new ArrayList<Autorizacao>();
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "login")
    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    @Column(name = "senha")
    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    @Column(name = "primeiro_nome")
    public String getPrimeiroNome() {
        return primeiroNome;
    }

    public void setPrimeiroNome(String primeiroNome) {
        this.primeiroNome = primeiroNome;
    }

    @Column(name = "ultimo_nome")
    public String getUltimoNome() {
        return ultimoNome;
    }

    public void setUltimoNome(String ultimoNome) {
        this.ultimoNome = ultimoNome;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_tipo")
    public Tipo getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(Tipo tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="atributo_usuario", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_usuario")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_atributo")})
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    public List<Atributo> getAtributo() {
        return atributo;
    }

    public void setAtributo(List<Atributo> atributo) {
        this.atributo = atributo;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_config")
    public ConfigHorarioLivre getConfig() {
        return config;
    }

    public void setConfig(ConfigHorarioLivre config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="autorizacao_usuario", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_usuario")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_autorizacao")})
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    public List<Autorizacao> getAutorizacao() {
        return autorizacao;
    }

    public void setAutorizacao(List<Autorizacao> autorizacao) {
        this.autorizacao = autorizacao;
    }

}
```

And I am facing this error:

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.horariolivre.entity.Key
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:835)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$7.cascade(CascadingAction.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:330)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:852)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:826)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:830)
    at com.horariolivre.dao.AtributoHome.persist(AtributoHome.java:37)
    at com.horariolivre.dao.AtributoHome$$FastClassByCGLIB$$97541e8a.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at com.horariolivre.dao.AtributoHome$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$26066f50.persist(<generated>)
    at com.horariolivre.service.UsuarioService.cadastra(UsuarioService.java:58)
    at com.horariolivre.controller.UsuarioController.cadastra_usuario(UsuarioController.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Abr 09, 2014 7:49:30 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
Abr 09, 2014 7:49:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
Grave: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/HorarioLivre2] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1] with root cause
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3215)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3117)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3446)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:328)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1233)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:403)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:554)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:755)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:724)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:475)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:270)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at com.horariolivre.dao.AtributoHome$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$26066f50.persist(<generated>)
    at com.horariolivre.service.UsuarioService.cadastra(UsuarioService.java:58)
    at com.horariolivre.controller.UsuarioController.cadastra_usuario(UsuarioController.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

That atribute Key is located in the class Atributo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "atributo")
public class Atributo implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6084758898903241369L;

    private int id;
    private Key key;
    private Value value;

    public Atributo() {
    }

    public Atributo(Key key, Value value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Atributo(String key, String value) {
        this.key = new Key(key);
        this.value = new Value(value);
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="key")
    public Key getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(Key key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="value")
    public Value getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Value value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

The saving operation is handled this way:

```
public boolean cadastra(String login, String senha, String primeiroNome, String ultimoNome, String tipoUsuario, String[] campo, String[] valor) {
    Tipo tipo_usuario = tipo.findByNome(tipoUsuario);
    List<Atributo> lista_atributos = new ArrayList<Atributo>();

    for(int i=0; i<campo.length; i++) {
        Key chave = key.findByNome(campo[i]);
        Value conteudo = new Value(valor[i]);
        value.persist(conteudo);
        lista_atributos.add(new Atributo(chave, conteudo));
        atributo.persist(lista_atributos.get(i));
    }

    return this.usuario.persist(new Usuario(login, senha, primeiroNome, ultimoNome, tipo_usuario, lista_atributos));
}
```

Someone can point a direction to the right way to persist this entity?

ps.: the full code of the project can be found here:

https://github.com/klebermo/webapp_horario_livre

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345598/hibernate-manytoone-only-works-with-cascadetype-all/18345715#18345715

Comment: how you save those entites? post your code about that. most likely you creating new object then save multiple time with cascade on.

Comment: I update the question with requested code? any ideas?

Comment: hey @bellabax, I try modify the anootations for the 'key' in entity 'Atributo', but after that I am geting the error 'detached entity passed to persist: om.horariolivre.entity.Key'. Do you can indicate another text like the previous one about this?

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception exactly? Is it `atributo.persist()` or `this.usuario.persist()`?

Comment: the exception is triggered by atributo.persist(), i guess, since the method cadastra() listed above is being executed until that line (including persisting normally the first Value in loop execution).

Comment: @KleberMota Could you provide the body of the method `key.findByNome()`?

Comment: I update the topic with the link for this project in github. The direct link for the code you asked is: https://github.com/klebermo/webapp_horario_livre/blob/9da705dc02d64194e87f90eb10003caba424b364/src/com/horariolivre/dao/KeyHome.java

Comment: @KleberMota Well, I can't see the method `findByNome`...

Comment: Update just now, try the link again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get to solve this issue. Let me share here the final code for the main players in this operation: Usuario.java / Atributo.java and Key / Value. In short terms, it was all about a combination of use `@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)` on class Atributo and `fetch=FetchType.LAZY` on class Usuario.

**Usuario.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuario")
public class Usuario implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7283129128268761582L;

    private int id;
    private String login;
    private String senha;
    private String primeiroNome;
    private String ultimoNome;
    private Tipo tipo;
    private ConfigHorarioLivre config;
    private List<Atributo> atributo;
    private List<Autorizacao> autorizacao;
    private List<HorarioLivre> horario_livre;

    public Usuario() {
    }

    public Usuario(String login, String senha) {
        this.setLogin(login);
        this.setSenha(senha);
    }

    public Usuario(String login, String senha, String primeiroNome, String ultimoNome, Tipo tipo, List<Atributo> atributos) {
        this.setLogin(login);
        this.setSenha(senha);
        this.setPrimeiroNome(primeiroNome);
        this.setUltimoNome(ultimoNome);
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.atributo = atributos;
        this.config = new ConfigHorarioLivre();
        this.autorizacao = new ArrayList<Autorizacao>();
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "login")
    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    @Column(name = "senha")
    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    @Column(name = "primeiro_nome")
    public String getPrimeiroNome() {
        return primeiroNome;
    }

    public void setPrimeiroNome(String primeiroNome) {
        this.primeiroNome = primeiroNome;
    }

    @Column(name = "ultimo_nome")
    public String getUltimoNome() {
        return ultimoNome;
    }

    public void setUltimoNome(String ultimoNome) {
        this.ultimoNome = ultimoNome;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_tipo")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    public Tipo getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(Tipo tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="atributo_usuario", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_usuario")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_atributo")})
    public List<Atributo> getAtributo() {
        return atributo;
    }

    public void setAtributo(List<Atributo> atributo) {
        this.atributo = atributo;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_config")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    public ConfigHorarioLivre getConfig() {
        return config;
    }

    public void setConfig(ConfigHorarioLivre config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="autorizacao_usuario", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_usuario")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_autorizacao")})
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    public List<Autorizacao> getAutorizacao() {
        return autorizacao;
    }

    public void setAutorizacao(List<Autorizacao> autorizacao) {
        this.autorizacao = autorizacao;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="horariolivre_usuario", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_usuario")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_horariolivre")})
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    public List<HorarioLivre> getHorario_livre() {
        return horario_livre;
    }

    public void setHorario_livre(List<HorarioLivre> horario_livre) {
        this.horario_livre = horario_livre;
    }

}
```

**Atributo.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "atributo")
public class Atributo implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6084758898903241369L;

    private int id;
    private Key key;
    private Value value;

    public Atributo() {
    }

    public Atributo(Key key, Value value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Atributo(String key, String value) {
        this.key = new Key(key);
        this.value = new Value(value);
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToOne( cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE} )
    @JoinColumn(name="key")
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    public Key getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(Key key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    @OneToOne( cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE} )
    @JoinColumn(name="value")
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    public Value getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Value value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

**Key.java**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "key")
public class Key implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int id;
    private String nome;

    public Key() {
    }

    public Key(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "nome", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

}
```

**Value.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "value")
public class Value implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6515224281217075194L;

    private int id;
    private String conteudo;

    public Value() {
    }

    public Value(String conteudo) {
        this.conteudo = conteudo;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "conteudo")
    public String getConteudo() {
        return conteudo;
    }

    public void setConteudo(String conteudo) {
        this.conteudo = conteudo;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are still using detached entities in your service layer. Maybe changing the cascade strategy helps in this particular case but the design is error prone. Another (bigger problem) is that your are persisting each and every entities in a separate transaction (for the same reason: because trx boundaries are on DAO and not on Service layer). This can lead to serious data integrity issues in case you have an exception in the middle of your service method.

Comment: actually, in the current state of my project, the methods from Service class which make access to database have the annotation @Transactional. See https://github.com/klebermo/webapp_horario_livre/tree/master/src/com/horariolivre/service

Comment: ah so you added the @Transactional everywhere, it was not the case before. this should have solved your original issue without the need for changing the cascade strategy...

Answer (score 2):

Your service methods are not transactional. Your transactions are opened before each DAO methods and committed after. Since the hibernate session is attached to the current transaction the session is always closed after returning from a DAO method. This results in detached entities in your service layer.
To quickly fix just add `@Transactional` to your service methods:

```
@Transactional
public boolean cadastra(String login, String senha, String primeiroNome, String ultimoNome, String tipoUsuario, String[] campo, String[] valor) {
...
}
```