# How do I update a JPA field that has "orphanRemoval=true"?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I’m using JPA 2.0 with Hibernate 4.1.0.Final.  I have this entity (uni-directional relationship between User and Address objects) …

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable
{

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_address", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "address_id"))
    private Set<Address> addresses;
```

In my “updateUser” method, I’m have this code

```
        user.setAddresses(addresses);
```

which calls

```
public void setAddresses(Set<Address> addresses)
{
    if (this.addresses == null)
    {
        this.addresses = new HashSet<Address>();
    }
    this.addresses.clear();
    if (addresses != null)
    {
        this.addresses.addAll(addresses);
    }   // if
}
```

The problem is the addresses only save if the “addresses” are new objects, as opposed to re-saving existing Address entities.  What do I need to do to update my user with existing addresses?

**Edit:** Here's how I save the entity ...

```
protected Object save(Object obj)
{
    if (obj != null)
    {
        final Object id = getId(obj);
        if (id == null)
        {
            m_entityManager.persist(obj);
        }
        else
        {
            obj = m_entityManager.merge(obj);
        }   // if
    }   // if
    return obj;
} // save
```

Comment: instead of `cascade` on `OneToMany` try to use `@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade(SAVE_UPDATE)` annotation on filed `addresses`, if you use hibernate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to save both the user and the addresses you need to call session.merge:

```
user.setAddresses(addresses);
session.merge(user);
```

The merge will be cascaded from User to Addresses, and it will work for both new Entities as for detached ones.

Also clearing the list and adding the elements back doesn't perform very well. i would recommend doing something like:

```
//always initialize the children ollections
private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<Address>();

//make sure equals/hashcode are implemented according to the business key semantics
//don't use the entity id for equals and hashcod

public void setAddresses(Set<Address> addresses) {  
    //1. remove the existing addresses that are not found in the new ones
    this.addresses.retainAll(addresses);
    //2. add the new addresses too, the common ones will be ignored by the Set semantics
    this.addresses.addAll(addresses);
}
```

Comment: I'm using a straight-up JPA implementation, but when I save my "user" entity. I am using "entityManager.persist(user)."  Is this what you were talking about whne you included "session.merge"?

Comment: Yes, you need to use entityManager.merge(user) when updating.

Comment: Hi, I'm already doing that.  I edited my question to show the code I use for saving.

Answer (score 1):

Best pratice for Collection properties is to init collection to a new empty collection to let Hibernate proxify it and manage object removal in the right way.
Try change you code as

```
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid-strategy", strategy = "org.collegeboard.springboard.core.util.SpringboardUUIDGenerator")
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable
{

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_address", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "address_id"))
    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<Address>;
```

Also look at [Hibernate @ManyToOne only works with CascadeType.ALL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345598/hibernate-manytoone-only-works-with-cascadetype-all/18345715#18345715) for correct annotation/persistace methods pairs

Comment: why are you using merge() instead of persist()? merge() create a new copy of your object and this object is not managed so you have to persist() it to make object changes effective